# Troubleshoot Linksys RE2000 Extender to TP Link W8968 Connection

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have a [Batelco (Bahrain ISP) TP Link TD-W8968](http://www.help.com.bh/portal/broadband_routers_tplink.asp) - 1.0.5 Build 140821 Rel.52209 - connected to the building's LAN and a Linksys RE2000 -    2.0.00, build 72, Jan 24, 2014  - extender to expand the wifi signal throughout the house.

For the last 3 weeks the [Linksys RE2000](http://www.linksys.com/us/support-product?pid=01t80000003K7ZPAA0) has not been functioning well. Most of the time a device uses the extender part of the network to connect to site or app server the connection times out. So the wifi signal works, but the internet does not. The only thing I think has changed is that I connected my Mac Mini using a LAN cable to the TP Link router.The TP Link is configured as an Access Point and Bridge Restrict has been disabled.

Here is my TP Link log for the last 10 minutes or so

```
Jun 6 04:22:21  daemon  alert   kernel: Intrusion -> IN=ppp0 OUT= MAC= SRC=222.186.15.34 DST=xx.xxx.xx.xxx LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=100 ID=256 PROTO=TCP SPT=6000 DPT=9200 WINDOW=16384 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 MARK=0x8000000
Jun 6 04:23:06  daemon  alert   kernel: INFO175E: connect server failed
Jun 6 04:38:24  daemon  alert   kernel: Intrusion -> IN=ppp0 OUT= MAC= SRC=212.164.151.56 DST=xx.xxx.xx.xxx LEN=60 TOS=0x02 PREC=0x00 TTL=52 ID=23538 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=58909 DPT=23 WINDOW=5792 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 MARK=0x8000000
Jun 6 04:53:59  daemon  alert   kernel: Intrusion -> IN=ppp0 OUT= MAC= SRC=111.74.239.61 DST=xx.xxx.xx.xxx LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=103 ID=256 PROTO=TCP SPT=6000 DPT=3389 WINDOW=16384 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 MARK=0x8000000
Jun 6 04:54:04  daemon  alert   kernel: INFO02D0: use dev Name br0
Jun 6 04:57:13  daemon  alert   kernel: INFO175E: connect server failed
Jun 6 05:18:26  daemon  alert   kernel: Intrusion -> IN=ppp0 OUT= MAC= SRC=89.154.89.100 DST=xx.xxx.xx.xxx LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=5005 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=4430 DPT=23 WINDOW=5840 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 MARK=0x8000000
Jun 6 05:24:57  daemon  alert   kernel: Intrusion -> IN=ppp0 OUT= MAC= SRC=89.217.74.136 DST=xx.xxx.xx.xxx LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=48 ID=15420 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=47839 DPT=23 WINDOW=14600 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 MARK=0x8000000
Jun 6 05:24:58  daemon  alert   kernel: Intrusion -> IN=ppp0 OUT= MAC= SRC=89.217.74.136 DST=xx.xxx.xx.xxx LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=48 ID=15421 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=47839 DPT=23 WINDOW=14600 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 MARK=0x8000000
Jun 6 05:28:11  daemon  alert   kernel: INFO02D0: use dev Name br0
Jun 6 05:31:20  daemon  alert   kernel: INFO175E: connect server failed
Jun 6 05:33:21  daemon  crit    kernel: eth1 Link UP 100 mbps full duplex
```

I do not see anything out of the ordinary or useful there. Here is the wifi setup

[image: TP Link Wifi setup]

I can reach the RE2000 on the network at 192.168.1.100 (TP Link at 192.168.1.1 ), but it also often times out. Here the ping result

```
traceroute 192.168.1.100
traceroute to 192.168.1.100 (192.168.1.100), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  re2000 (192.168.1.100)  3.590 ms  2.674 ms  8.877 ms
```

But just loading the status took 1 minute and 19 seconds. Loading the Dashboard was stalled for 40 seconds. 
Is it perhaps because of the many wifi networks around?

[image: wifi neworks shown by RE2000]

According to the documentation http://downloads.linksys.com/downloads/userguide/MAN_RE2000V2_3425-01650C_mUG,0.pdf  60% signal strenght or 3 bars and up should be fine. And that I do have..I did not have the RE2000 log running so just turned it on now. But here it is

```
RE2000 syslogd started: BusyBox v1.12.1
RE2000 PROC INIT OK!
RE2000 
RE2000 2.4GHz Wireless
RE2000 MAC                AID BSS PSM WMM MIMOPS  RSSI0  RSSI1  RSSI2  PhMd      BW    MCS   SGI   STBC  Idle   Rate   
RE2000 xxxx  2   0   0   1   3       -68    -66    0      HTMIX     40M   15    0     0     0      270    
RE2000 
RE2000 
RE2000 5GHz Wireless
RE2000 MAC                AID BSS PSM WMM MIMOPS  RSSI0  RSSI1  RSSI2  PhMd      BW    MCS   SGI   STBC  Idle   Rate   
RE2000 
RE2000 2.4GHz Wireless
RE2000 MAC                AID BSS PSM WMM MIMOPS  RSSI0  RSSI1  RSSI2  PhMd      BW    MCS   SGI   STBC  Idle   Rate   
RE2000 xxx  1   0   1   1   3       -62    -68    0      HTMIX     20M   7     0     0     257    65     
RE2000 
RE2000 xxxx  2   0   0   1   3       -68    -66    0      HTMIX     40M   15    0     0     0      270    
RE2000 
RE2000 
RE2000 5GHz Wireless
RE2000 MAC                AID BSS PSM WMM MIMOPS  RSSI0  RSSI1  RSSI2  PhMd      BW    MCS   SGI   STBC  Idle   Rate
```

And here is its wifi setup

```
Wi-Fi Protected SetupTM Status: Configured
Wireless Band:  2.4 GHz
Network Name (SSID):    TP-LINK_D4B8BB
Security:   WPA2-PSK
5 GHz Wireless      Wi-Fi Protected SetupTM Status: Unconfigured
Wireless Band:  5 GHz
Network Name (SSID):    LinksysExtender00896_5Gmedia
Security:   Disabled
```

Would appreciate some help troubleshooting so I can use the RE2000 to access the web, I spent quite a bit of money on, well again.

Comment: using `airport -s` I saw most routers nearby were using channel 9 so changed to 7 on TP Link. Will see if that helps in the communication between TP Link and the RE2000

Comment: Doing traceroutes or pings from the area where the RE2000 is located are very slow. Often 100ms to reach the TP Link over wifi. Sites like Facebook time-out often still. Pinging the extender from the network also often times out. So seems link the channel is not the issue.

Comment: Changed the TP Link beacon interval to 50 to see if that helps the RE2000 getting on the web quicker and allowing it to play better with the TP Link. See http://routerguide.net/beacon-interval-best-optimal-setting-improve-wireless-speed/

Comment: Tried beacon interval 200. For a while no improvement. Then I had to unplug the device for a while and plugin again and now signal strength is at four bars or 80%. Perhaps because the Linksys RE2000 cooled down? Does get hot often and quite quickly.

Comment: Doing some testing with removing the lan cable from Mac Mini to WP Link and keeping the building lan cable in the wan/lan slot. Seems to help with making the RE2000 able to access the web. But will need time to confirm. Also wonder why..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nobody came up with real suggestions with the current setup. It has continued to work on and off sporadically. I guess too much interference from the walls and still too far from the main router. So the solution is to live for it for now, work closer to the main router and in the future fix the local LAN network or find a wireless router that is twice as powerful to cover more ground and that then allows the extender to stay connected better.